# "Could NOT find Python" error when compiling QGIS source code

Tags: qgis, compile

I tried to complile QGIS source code according to the method from [QGIS's INSTALL.md](http://%5Chttps://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL.md) on my windows computer and did't know why CMake couldn't find the proper Python version although I had added related environment variables in system PATH. I tried some solutions but they didn't seem to work.
[image: QGIS INSTALL.md screenshot]

How can I solve it?

[image: error screenshot]